# Check processes that are running - java

Tags: java, unix

I want to write a java application that is to be deployed on a unix box. I need to check the running processes - that are running on the box. Could someone show me an example / point me in the right direction?

Comment: java.lang.ProcessBuilder + ps

Comment: What do you mean "check the running processes"? What information about the processes do you need exactly?

Comment: Have you tried googling for "How to check running processes linux"

Comment: That's fine but i was told that i would need to have an external .sh file called by java, because if java checks it will eventually rack up and ran out of memory. Not sure why my question was marked out either. Anyways, just want to check if a particular application(s) is running on the box, nothing more.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to find the running java processes, you can use

`ps -ef | grep java`

If you need to check which ports are in use,

`netstat -tupln`

Answer (score 3):

I came across some alternatives for `ps aux | grep java` provided by Java that need less typing:

```
jcmd
```

and

```
jps -v
```

The option `-v` will show the arguments passed to the JVM.

If you get **process information unavailable** this could be because the process is running with OpenJDK.
If you are root and the process was started with a non-root user you can use the following to see the details (replace `<user>` with the username):

```
sudo -u <user> jps -v
```

---

Another nice feature of `jcmd` is that you can display the Java version that a specific process uses (in case `ps aux | grep java` does not show it), that's how I came across the two (replace `<pid>` with the process id):

```
jcmd <pid> VM.version
```